# jQuery onClick Function not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function that I placed inside the document.ready and the function is called from onclick of a specific button. Nothing happens when the button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    function myFunctionDelete()
    {
        alert("Delete Clicked.");
    }
}
```

and here is the corresponding HTML linked to that button.

```
<form action="edit.php" method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr id="formTitle" name="formTitle"><strong>Edit Event Now</strong></tr>
    <input type="hidden" id="deletedHidden" name="deletedHidden" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="dateForm2" name="dateForm2" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="titleEditOld" name="titleEditOld" value="" />
    <tr id="formTitle"><td><label id="titleLabel" for="Title"><strong>Title:</strong></label><input id="titleEdit" name="titleEdit" type="text" value="Event Title">
    <tr id="formTitle"><td><label for="startTimeHours"><strong>Time:</strong></label><select id="startHours" name="startHours"><option>--</option>                                                                                        <option>12</option>                                                                                         <option>1</option><option>2</option>                                                                                        <option>3</option><option>4</option>
                                                                                          <option>5</option><option>6</option>
                                                                                          <option>7</option><option>8</option>
                                                                                          <option>9</option><option>10</option>
                                                                                          <option>11</option></select>
    <select id="startMinutes" name="startMinutes"><option>--</option>                                                                                         <option>00</option>
                                                                                          <option>05</option><option>10</option>
                                                                                          <option>15</option><option>20</option>
                                                                                          <option>25</option><option>30</option>
                                                                                          <option>35</option><option>40</option>
                                                                                          <option>45</option><option>50</option>
                                                                                          <option>55</option></select>

    <input type="radio" name="AMPM" value="am">am
    <input type="radio" name="AMPM" value="pm">pm<br>
    <p><strong>All Day Event?</strong>
    <input type="checkbox" name="AllDay" value="true"></p>                                                                
    <tr id=formTitle"><td><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionDelete()">Delete Event</button>
    </table>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle of the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: it works fine for me go here and see: http://jsbin.com/ojeweb/1/edit  Have you included the Jquery library in the head of your page?

Comment: Your html is invalid.  thats why your code is acting up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that your `myFunctionDelete` function is not accessible globally, as it's defined within the `ready` event for the document.  You'll need to move the function out of the event handler.  In other words, change:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    function myFunctionDelete()
    {
        alert("Delete Clicked.");
    }
}
```

To:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   // Any code that should be run when the DOM is ready
});

// This is now a global function
function myFunctionDelete()
{
   alert("Delete Clicked.");
}
```

Comment: I say the exact same thing as you, with more explanation, AND provide an alternate solution, and your post gets 3 votes and mine gets -1. This site confuses the crap out of me sometimes ... *\*sigh\**

Comment: that does not work - try putting that in a fiddle with the OP's original HTML on this page.

Comment: @blachawk - Well, according to the OP who *accepted* this answer, it - and I quote - *"works perfectly."*

Comment: @MikeChristensen  But according to your knowledge, are you going to correct him?

Answer (score 4):

What you've done here is defined a function from inside the function you've specified will be the event handler for `document.ready`. This means your `myFunctionDelete` function will have its scope limited to that of the `document.ready` function, and any other Javascript routines will not be able to access it.

You only need to put one-time initilalization logic within the `document.ready` event handler, not all your code needs to go there, *especially* if you're just using the HTML `onclick="..."` attribute.

Also, you're missing a `);` at the end of the `document.ready` event handler.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

});

function myFunctionDelete()
{
    alert("Delete Clicked.");
}
```

Or ditch the `onclick` and use this:

```
<button id="deleteButton">Delete Event</button>
```

With this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#deleteButton').click(function()
    {
        alert("Delete Clicked.");
    });
});
```