# function is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: html, d3.js

I'm using [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8) to try and update a visualization I created. I'm literally using the same piece of code, and yet I keep getting an error that says `Uncaught ReferenceError: liste is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick`. I looked a bit around and tried various solutions, but none of them seemed to work. Here is a code snippet :

```
<div id="option">
<input
    name="updateButton" 
    type="button" 
    value="50"
    onclick="liste(50)"/>
</div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js'></script>
<script src='script.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
```

And my function `liste` works perfectly fine, since when I launch it "by hand" from my script it does what it's supposed to do. Here is what it does :

```
function liste(seuil){
    for (var i = 0; i < seuil; i++) {
        dataSeuil[i] = data[i];

    }
    graphe(dataSeuil);
}
```

The `graphe` function is the plotting function.

Here is a screenshot of what happens when I click the button. I've tried putting my `<script> </script>` tags before the  tag but it doesn't help.
[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: will it work if u define that function as an inline script? might be the path you have is wrong

Comment: I defined the function as an inline script, but since it's using `data` I get an error that say `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: Why don't you do the other way around? `d3.select("input").on("click", function(){ liste(50)})`.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure onclick function is outside of the ready handler . Please check the below link

> [jQuery onClick Function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922303/jquery-onclick-function-not-working)